# Confusing myself extracting data from core data to two different view controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm new to Core Data and think I may be making things a little harder on myself than it needs to be, because I seem to be repeating code across View Controllers.  I have successfully managed to populate a table with my core data entries with this code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ClientListViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var clientItems : [Client] = []

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return clientItems.count
    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let items = clientItems[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = items.name
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }

    func getData() {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
        clientItems = try context.fetch(Client.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            print("Fetch Failed")

        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let item = clientItems[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(item)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do {
                clientItems = try context.fetch(Client.fetchRequest())
            } catch {
                print("Fetch Failed")

            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getData()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

This code displays a clients name in the table as expected but when I click on the the cell I want it to load up my new view showing all the clients info stored for them in core data. To start I want the navigation bar title to be the persons name that was tapped from the cell on the previous View Controller but my code always shows the first entry because I'm saying [0] how can the data provided be from the actual row selected in the table on the other View Controller.

I'm confused and seem to be repeating unnecessary code in the process. Here is my second View Controllers code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ClientViewController: UIViewController {

    var clientItems : [Client] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        getData()
        navigationItem.title = String(describing: clientItems[0].name!)
        print(clientItems[0].name!)

    }

    func getData() {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            clientItems = try context.fetch(Client.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            print("Fetch Failed")

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How you are passing data from one Viewcotroller to another viewcontroller.?

Comment: I had tried var passData: SecondViewController!

Comment: Please send the Client object from `ClientListViewController` to `ClientViewController`. And use that object instead of client[0].

Comment: This worked for me I was passing them the wrong way round so this has helped :)